# How do create Bootstrap Nav Bar In WordPress using NavWalker and bootstrap.min.css

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

How do I convert below Bootstrap `NavBar` to Dynamic WordPress Navbar using `NavWalker` and bootstrap.min.css.
I know `NavWalker` uses bootstrap.css, **But I want to use the minified version(bootstrap.min.css)**.

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

can someone Help Me?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, I was using the latest bootstrap 5 instead of bootstrap 4. It's working well now